# Failed Vagrant up rerun for VirtualBox gives error

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Recently, I tried to setup a Vagrant box with VirtualBox as VM provider.
On my first attempt, Vagrant created virtual box correctly but failed due to some chef error.

I resolved the error pointed by chef and reran the vagrant up command again, but this time I got following error:

> Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
>   would collide with some other application that is already listening on
>   these ports.

What seems like upon failure, vagrant did not clean up ports it associated with VBox. I even tried removing the .vagrant directory and the machine from Virtual Boxes directory it created. Still getting the same error. Only way I was able to run it by changing port forwarding in the vagrant file.

Please let me know if there is any way to force vagrant auto correct/clean settings upon failure; as I don't want to change vagrantfile upon failures which can happen for many reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `auto_correct` option you could use

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
    auto_correct: true
end
```

From https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

> It is common when running multiple Vagrant machines to unknowingly
>   create forwarded port definitions that collide with each other (two
>   separate Vagrant projects forwarded to port 8080, for example).
>   Vagrant includes built-in mechanism to detect this and correct it,
>   automatically.
>
> Port collision detection is always done. Vagrant will not allow you to
>   define a forwarded port where the port on the host appears to be
>   accepting traffic or connections.
>
> Port collision auto-correction must be manually enabled for each
>   forwarded port, since it is often surprising when it occurs and can
>   lead the Vagrant user to think that the port was not properly
>   forwarded. Enabling auto correct is easy:
>
> The final :auto_correct parameter set to true tells Vagrant to auto
>   correct any collisions. During a vagrant up or vagrant reload, Vagrant
>   will output information about any collisions detections and auto
>   corrections made, so you can take notice and act accordingly.